# Having the same effective mass for conduction band and valence band?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

According to eqn 28.22 in Ashcroft and Mermin, the chemical potential is independent of temperature if the effective masses of valence and conduction band are the same. What is the consequence of this band symmetry? and in what materials would you observe this?

Comment: Generally you don't observe this. None of Si, Ge, nor GaAs have this property.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for the comment. I am wondering if we open up a bandgap at the Dirac point, you would get this case where effective mass of electron and hole the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known semiconductor with equal effective masses of the conduction and valence bands. The mentioned statement in Ashcroft and Mermin obviously refers to the position of the Fermi level (i.e. chemical potential) in the band gap of a hypothetical semiconductor with equal effective densities of states of the conduction and the valence bands, which are determined in the parabolic approximation by the effective density of states masses, i.e. curvatures of the minimum of the conduction band and the maximum of the valence band. In this hypothetical case, the Fermi level (chemical potential) is energetically positioned exactly in the middle of the band gap independently of temperature.

See semiconductor textbooks, e.g., S.M. Sze, Semiconductor Physics and Technology, Chaper 2.6 "Intrinsic carrier density".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am wondering if we open up a bandgap at the Dirac point, you would get this case where effective mass of electron and hole the same?